# How to bind engine when I want, when using declarative_base in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

Here's my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

database_url = 'mysql://some_path'
engine = create_engine(database_url)
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}

metadata = Base.metadata
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

It works, but...
**Is it possible to bind engine when I want, not only at import time?** So I can wrap this implementation into class.

For now, I get

```
    class Users(Base):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.5-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative.py", line 1231, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.5-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative.py", line 1122, in _as_declarative
    **table_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.5-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 209, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.5-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 260, in _init
    msg="No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData. "
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.5-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 2598, in _bind_or_error
    raise exc.UnboundExecutionError(msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData. Pass an engine to the Table via autoload_with=<someengine>, or associate the MetaData with an engine via metadata.bind=<someengine>
```

when engine is not specified: `Base = declarative_base()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use late binding with `autoload` option set to `True`, since SQLAlchemy can't compile mappers without knowledge of database schema.

Answer (score 10):

At least with SQLAlchemy 0.9 you can defer the binding by using DeferredReflection. See the example in the [Using Reflection with Declarative section of the manual](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeferredReflection).

There, you can find the following example (simplified):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, DeferredReflection

Base = declarative_base(cls=DeferredReflection)

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    bars = relationship("Bar")

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'

Base.prepare(e)
```

e is the engine.

Comment: The link is dead